# How can i populate an array of pointers, type char, in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

For example, lets have `char *names[5] = {"Emanuel", "Michael", "John", "George", "Sam"}`. How can I fill *names[5] using for loop,  using `setw()` function to limit the number of input characters.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead?

Comment: _"How can I fill `*names[5]`"_  Accessing `names[5]` gets you out of bounds. The maximum index you can use is 4.

Answer (score 1):

You use the C++ Standard Library instead, specifically [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
// empty container of names
std::vector<std::string> names;

// Populated container of names
std::vector<std::string> populatedNames = { "Emanuel", "Michael", "John", "George", "Sam" };

// add some names to both:
names.push_back("Terry");
names.push_back("Foobar");
populatedNames.push_back("Ashley");

// how many names in each?
std::cout << "Our once empty container contains " << names.size() << " names" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Our pre-populated container contains " << populatedNames.size() << " names" << std::endl;

// print names:
for (auto s : names)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
for (auto s : populatedNames)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

If you need to restrict the characters in the names, it might be better to do that when receiving the input:

```
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
const auto maxLength = 10;
if (name.length() > maxLength)
{
    // inform user that name will be truncated etc, or ask for new name
    ...
    name.erase(maxLength-1);
}
names.push_back(name);
```

However, you can also just iterate through the container and shorten all names:

```
for (auto& s : names)
{
    if (s.length() > maxLength)
    {
        s.erase(maxLength-1);
    }
}
```